# UWP BackgroundDownloader freezes even on PC

Tags: c#, download, background, uwp

```
string url = "http://any_urls";
    MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer();

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Debug.WriteLine("Download started");
        var file = Download().Result; // <-- Here's where it stucks
        Debug.WriteLine("Download finished");

        player.Source = MediaSource.CreateFromStorageFile(file);
        player.Play();
    }

    private async Task<StorageFile> Download()
    {
        StorageFile destinationFile = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync(
            "data.mp3", CreationCollisionOption.GenerateUniqueName);
        BackgroundDownloader downloader = new BackgroundDownloader();
        DownloadOperation download = downloader.CreateDownload(new Uri(url), destinationFile);
        await download.StartAsync();
        return destinationFile;
    }
```

I've tested on both PC and phone and they both froze the whole process. Can anybody fix this, or any good alternative to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Forgot to call "AsTask" method when starting download.
2. Can't have async costructors.

   ```
   public MainPage()
   {
       this.InitializeComponent();
   }

   private async void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   {
       Debug.WriteLine("Download started");
       var file = await DownloadAsync();
       Debug.WriteLine("Download finished");

       player.Source = MediaSource.CreateFromStorageFile(file);
       player.Play();
   }

   private async Task<StorageFile> DownloadAsync()
   {
       StorageFile destinationFile = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync(
           "data.mp3", CreationCollisionOption.GenerateUniqueName);
       BackgroundDownloader downloader = new BackgroundDownloader();
       DownloadOperation download = downloader.CreateDownload(new Uri(url), destinationFile);
       await download.StartAsync().AsTask();
       return destinationFile;
   }
   ```